# One click building my project with Cmake & Msbuild (vs2010) with a batch file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, batch-file, cmake

I have to make a one click build of a projet made for Cmake ( already works on Linux) with a batch file that downloads all the 3rd party libraries and compiles them. (win64)

1. If posible i dont want to change projets CMakeLists.txt.
2. I already build the project in VS2010 GUI. and i had to change the folowing:
   a. had to change Configuration properties-C++-Command line: added /DWNT /D "CAD_STATIC"
   b. had to add a long list of libraries in Configuration properties- Linker input- additional dependencies.
   c. add library directories for those libraries
   d. add include directories.
3. The project compiled and worked ok.

Now i need to make the same with only batch commands. 
I already build the project file with cmake with:

```
cmake ..\projectsource -G "Visual Studio 10 Win64" -DGLEW_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=%myroot%\glew\trunk\lib\Release\glew.lib -DGLUT_glut_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=%myroot%\freeglut\trunk\lib\Release\freeglut.lib -DMKL_LIBRARIES:FILEPATH=%myroot%\mkl\em64t\lib\mkl_core.lib -DOpenCascade_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=%myroot%\OpenCascade
```

Now i need a command like "devenv project.sln /useenv "  that does the same as the stuff i did under #2.

I tried with a env include & lib like:

```
set "include=%myroot%\glew\trunk\include;%myroot%\freeglut\trunk\include;%myroot%\mkl\include;%myroot%\qt\include;%myroot%\OpenCascade\include\oce;%myroot%\trimo\src\CadModel;%include%"
set "lib=%myroot%\glew\trunk\lib\Release\*.lib;%myroot%\freeglut\trunk\lib\Release\*.lib;%myroot%\mkl\em64t\lib\*.lib;%myroot%"\qt\lib\*.lib;%myroot%\OpenCascade\Win64\lib\*.lib;%lib%"
```

All the help is very much appreciated. I'm stuck. Thanks

Edit:
I got another problem:

1. How can i unlink a library that gets linked in a project.sln automaticly by cmake?
2. will "lib=%myroot%\glew\trunk\lib\Release*.lib; link all the .lib files like u would get if u put all the libs in a vs2010 gui -Linker input- additional dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already setting the required `include` and `lib` variables, then probably all that's missing is:

```
set "cl=/DWNT /DCAD_STATIC"
```

then you should be able to use

```
devenv project.sln /useenv /build
```

Note, you've also got `libpath` available to set search paths for the libraries if required.

**Answers to further questions**

1. I don't know of a way to do that.
2. No.  I hadn't noticed you were doing that in your original question - sorry!  The LIB env var sets search paths in which libs could be found, it's not for the full path to the actual lib itself.

What you're trying to achieve is exactly the sort of scenario at which CMake excels.  You're fighting CMake here when it's probably the solution to the problems :-)

If I were you, I'd edit the CMakeLists.txt to include things like:

```
SET(MY_ROOT <path to %myroot%>)

FIND_LIBRARY(GLEW_LIBRARY glew ${MY_ROOT}/glew/trunk/lib/Release)
IF(NOT GLEW_LIBRARY)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "glew.lib not found in ${MY_ROOT}/glew/trunk/lib/Release")
ENDIF()

FIND_LIBRARY(GLUT_glut_LIBRARY freeglut ${MY_ROOT}/freeglut/trunk/lib/Release)
IF(NOT GLUT_glut_LIBRARY)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "freeglut.lib not found in ${MY_ROOT}/freeglut/trunk/lib/Release")
ENDIF()

FIND_LIBRARY(MKL_LIBRARIES mkl_core ${MY_ROOT}/mkl/em64t/Release)
IF(NOT MKL_LIBRARIES)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "mkl_core.lib not found in ${MY_ROOT}/mkl/em64t/Release")
ENDIF()

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MY_ROOT}/OpenCascad)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DWNT -DCAD_STATIC)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(<your target>
                      ${GLEW_LIBRARY}
                      ${GLUT_glut_LIBRARY}
                      ${MKL_LIBRARIES}
                      <any other libs...>
                      )
```

This is all Windows-specific, and Release-specific.  You could adapt the `FIND_LIBRARY` calls to cater for Unix/OSX options too, or you could wrap this in `IF(WIN32) ... ENDIF()` blocks.

You could also do `FIND_LIBRARY` calls for the Debug versions too if required (giving them different variable names) and adding them like:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(<your target>
                      optimized ${GLEW_LIBRARY}
                      optimized ${GLUT_glut_LIBRARY}
                      optimized ${MKL_LIBRARIES}
                      debug ${GLEW_LIBRARY_DEBUG}
                      debug ${GLUT_glut_LIBRARY_DEBUG}
                      debug ${MKL_LIBRARIES_DEBUG}
                      <any other libs...>
                      )
```

You'll also be able to remove whatever libraries you want from whatever targets you want by modifying the list of libs passed in the `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` call(s).

If you want to grab all *.lib files in a directory, add something like this:

```
FILE(GLOB ALL_GLEW_LIBS "${MY_ROOT}/glew/trunk/lib/Release/*.lib")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(<your target> ${ALL_GLEW_LIBS})
```

If you do use the `GLOB` call, and you also need Debug *and* Release, be sure to prefix each list item with `debug` or `optimized` as appropriate, e.g.

```
FOREACH(GLEW_ITR ${ALL_GLEW_LIBS_RELEASE})
  SET(ALL_GLEW_LIBS ${ALL_GLEW_LIBS} optimized ${GLEW_ITR})
ENDFOREACH()

FOREACH(GLEW_ITR ${ALL_GLEW_LIBS_DEBUG})
  SET(ALL_GLEW_LIBS ${ALL_GLEW_LIBS} debug ${GLEW_ITR})
ENDFOREACH()

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(<your target> ${ALL_GLEW_LIBS})
```

If all this is then catered for by CMake, you don't need to set any env vars in the batch script; you just do:

```
devenv project.sln /build
```